# Call a procedure from another unit without "uses"

Tags: delphi

In C++, if I have to call a function from another namespace, say `foo`, I have two options: adding the `using namespace foo;` above my code or specifying the namespace when I perform the call, that is `foo::myFunction()`.

In Delphi, is there a construct corresponding to the second alternative?

Comment: I don't see how your C++ scenarios have anything to do with the title. How are they related to using units in Delphi? They involve the same base word *use*, but that's about it.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Pascal's units behave much like namespaces of just one code file. So, the scenarios are an valid metaphor from an C++ POV.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't. If an identifier (such as a function, like `myFunction`) is declared in unit `foo`, then in a different unit, `bar`, say, you cannot use `myFunction` without adding `foo` to the `uses` clause either in the `implemantation` or in the `interface` section.

**Some discussion**

Let's say that you have two functions `MyFunc`, one in `foo` and one in `bar`. Let's say you're in `foo`. If you don't `add` bar to one of the `uses` lists, then `MyFunc` will refer to `foo.MyFunc`, and you cannot access the other function. If you add `bar` to one of the `uses` lists, then `MyFunc` will still refer to the local function `foo.MyFunc`, but you can access the other by writing `bar.MyFunc`. To reduce the risk of confusion, you could choose always to be explicit and write `foo.MyFunc` and `bar.MyFunc`, and never only `MyFunc`.

A common scenario is this: you got an identifier `ident` in both `foo` and `bar` (they could be very different), and in `MyUnit`, you have both `foo` and `bar` in some `uses` list. Then, in `MyUnit`, `ident` will refer either to `foo.ident` or `bar.ident`, *depending on which unit comes last in the uses clauses*. To use the other one, you have to be explicit about the unit (like `foo.ident` or `bar.ident`). Of course, to reduce the risk of making mistakes, you could always be explicit (e.g. write `foo.ident` even if `foo` comes last, so that `ident` also refers to `foo.ident`).

A common mistake is to confuse `Windows.TBitmap` with `Graphics.TBitmap`. Normally, `TBitmap` refers to `Graphics.TBitmap` (the `Windows` unit usually comes early in `uses` clauses). This confusion has been treated at SO.

Comment: Ok thanks, so if I have a procedure with the same name both in unit foo and in unit bar, I am screwed?

Comment: Ahem, you seem to take topicstarter's "first" and "second" alternative in wrong order